# Select Count Row then update value

Tags: mysql, sql

Just need some idea

Is there a way I can Select the count then update its value?

Here is my code to be edit.

I'm getting the number of new message in my table `message`

```
select count(id) as new from message where owner_id = '1' and status = '1' and isRecieve = '0'
```

When I get the number of message I want it to set all the `message` got from `select` query to isRecieve = 1

is there a way once I query I updte all isRecieve to 1?

like

```
 select count(id) as new from message where owner_id = '1' and status = '1' and isRecieve = '0' then update isRecieve = 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not select `COUNT` for your case. In fact, what your are trying to achieve is:

- UPDATE corresponding records
- Discover, how many rows was touched

This can be resolved with:

```
UPDATE 
  message 
SET 
  isReceive = '1' 
WHERE 
  owner_id = '1' 
  AND 
  status = '1' 
  AND 
  isRecieve = '0'
```

and then either do

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT()
```

to retrieve affected rows in SQL, or do something like [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/mysqli_affected_rows) in application (function is in PHP, but the same thing is available in any mysql connection driver in any language).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE message set 
    isRecieve = 1 where 
    owner_id = '1' and 
    status = '1' and 
    isRecieve = '0' and 
    exists (
        select 1 from message where 
            owner_id = '1' and 
            status = '1' and 
            isRecieve = '0'
            group by id having count(*) = 1
    )
```